# how to use process management start and end dates in the ranged dimension II in icCube

Tags: mdx, iccube

icCube can process ranged dimensions to solve complex modeling solutions for process management. [Here](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_ranged_2.php) an example is given for order date and ship date. Nice example, which is almost applicable, but not entirely.

I want to display changes with their latest phase. The changes come from an ITSM software SAAS solution. Simplified, a change flows through the following stages:

- to be authorized
- work in progress
- to be reviewed
- closed

Each stage has a start- and end date. And there are no gaps.

Now I would like to show the life-cycle of a change (or multiple changes) in a chart using the solution of the ranged II dimension. But I get the following chart:

[image: The Range Dimension II solution presents incorrectly 3 changes on day 20. It should be just one - the green one.]

How can I produce the required outcome. Meaning, only show the latest stage of a change during a certain time interval?

Comment: can you include some csv or similar with some data to work with ?

Comment: I added the schema and a sample dashboard to the backup environment. /icCube/doc/ic3report/version/6-dev?name=%2Fusers%2Farthur%2Fexample%20-%20stackoverflow%20-%20ranged%20dimension%20II

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions work.

1) For the range solution, you need to add a measure that uses [CLOSE aggregation](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/facts_aggregation.php) mode on the **Time Dimension** as we want the 'state' as of the last day of any time period. Also, both dates are included when using range, so end date should be one day before the start of the next bucket.

You can use [Sum](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Sum.php) or [Eval](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Eval.php) instead of [Aggregate](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Aggregate.php). Eval will be faster if the same time period is reused multiple times in the same query as the subcube is cached.

```
CREATE MEMBER [#changes ITD 2] as Eval( compactSet(NULL:[Time].[Time].currentMember) , ([Time].[Time].defaultMember,[Measures].[# changes (based on delta)]) )
```

2) For Purple Frog one, I'd use [compactSet](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/CompactSet.php) for the calculated member as without the calculated function will quickly degradated when getting more an more data. It's 365 days for each year, so if you've 10 years you'll have 3650 sums without de compactSet. With the compactSet, we can use it as the measure is [additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map), instead of 10 years will have something like, 9 (years) + 11 (months) + 31(days) , that is a lot less on the worst scenario.

Which one to use ?

1) It uses more memory but the performance is faster and amazingly stable as we're using the last day of the period value. Adding other time hierarchies might give some unexpected results.

```
CREATE MEMBER [#changes ITD] as Aggregate( compactSet(NULL:[Time].[Time].currentMember) , [Measures].[# changes (based on delta)] )
```

2) It uses less memory, we only save two points, but it a bit slower.

On both I'd pay attention that adding, and using, other Time hierarchies and Time dimensions might give some 'strange' results.

Here the updated schema ( [#changes ITD] definition is included)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<schemaFactory revisionNumber="11">
    <schemaDefinition name="Phases - ranged dimension II" description="issue description StackOverflow" group="StackOverflow" loadOnStartup="false">
        <activateIncrementalLoad>false</activateIncrementalLoad>
        <useUnknownMembersInFacts>false</useUnknownMembersInFacts>
        <autoCleanUpTableColumns>false</autoCleanUpTableColumns>
        <useFactPartitioning>false</useFactPartitioning>
        <callGarbageCollector>NONE</callGarbageCollector>
        <backup>NONE</backup>
        <nonEmptyCachePolicy>NONE</nonEmptyCachePolicy>
        <nonEmptyCacheType>REGULAR</nonEmptyCacheType>
        <nonEmptyCachePersistency>MEMORY</nonEmptyCachePersistency>
        <storagePolicy>DEFAULT</storagePolicy>
        <hierarchyUniqueNameStyle>IncludeDimensionName</hierarchyUniqueNameStyle>
        <inMemoryDS name="manual">
            <memoryDataTable tableName="facts" rowLimit="-1" id="c41cc2b5-1412-4da1-8e0e-3bd1b07e9d66">
                <column name="start" tableType="STRING" type="DATE" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="end" tableType="STRING" type="DATE" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="phase" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="chg" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="#changes" tableType="STRING" type="INTEGER" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <addRowNumber>false</addRowNumber>
                <stringDateConverter>d MMM, yyyy</stringDateConverter>
                <stringDateConverterLocale>en</stringDateConverterLocale>
                <trimStrings>true</trimStrings>
                <columnSeparator>;</columnSeparator>
                <commentMarker>#</commentMarker>
                <dataAsString>start;end;phase;chg;#changes
1 January, 2018;31 January, 2018; a;chg001;1
1 February, 2018;4 March, 2018;b;chg001;1
5 March, 2018;19 March, 2018;c;chg001;1
20 March, 2018;19 March, 2018;d;chg001;1
20 March, 2018;2 June, 2018;e;chg001;1
</dataAsString>
            </memoryDataTable>
            <memoryDataTable tableName="phases" rowLimit="-1" id="b24aaebb-7ce3-42a9-bab0-a54bc4c4b896">
                <column name="phase" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <addRowNumber>false</addRowNumber>
                <stringDateConverter></stringDateConverter>
                <trimStrings>true</trimStrings>
                <columnSeparator>,</columnSeparator>
                <commentMarker>#</commentMarker>
                <dataAsString>phase
a
b
c
d
e
</dataAsString>
            </memoryDataTable>
            <memoryDataTable tableName="changes" rowLimit="-1" id="8ba9aaca-0d93-49b1-851f-4f325e05bbbe">
                <column name="chg" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <addRowNumber>false</addRowNumber>
                <stringDateConverter></stringDateConverter>
                <trimStrings>true</trimStrings>
                <columnSeparator>;</columnSeparator>
                <commentMarker>#</commentMarker>
                <dataAsString>chg
chg001
chg002
chg003</dataAsString>
            </memoryDataTable>
            <memoryDataTable tableName="facts - delta" rowLimit="-1" id="aea29582-84e2-4ef4-a169-5d9549141ba6">
                <column name="date" tableType="STRING" type="DATE" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="phase" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="chg" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="delta" tableType="STRING" type="INTEGER" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <addRowNumber>false</addRowNumber>
                <stringDateConverter>d MMM, yyyy</stringDateConverter>
                <stringDateConverterLocale>en</stringDateConverterLocale>
                <trimStrings>true</trimStrings>
                <columnSeparator>;</columnSeparator>
                <commentMarker>#</commentMarker>
                <dataAsString>date;phase;chg;delta
1 January, 2018;a;chg001;1
1 February, 2018;b;chg001;1
5 March, 2018;c;chg001;1
20 March, 2018;d;chg001;1
20 March, 2018;e;chg001;1
1 February, 2018;a;chg001; -1
5 March, 2018;b;chg001;-1
20 March, 2018;c;chg001;-1
20 March, 2018;d;chg001;-1
13 June, 2018;e;chg001;-1
</dataAsString>
            </memoryDataTable>
        </inMemoryDS>
        <multiLevelDimension dataTableId="8ba9aaca-0d93-49b1-851f-4f325e05bbbe" isTimeDimension="false" isDefaultTimeDimension="false" isIndexingByRange="false" id="0c4cf980-73d9-4c42-ae47-a300421c29a2" name="Change">
            <multiLevelHierarchy hasAllLevel="true" allLevelName="All-Level" allMemberName="All" name="Change" isDefault="true">
                <level name="change" nameUnique="false" nameUniqueInParent="false" keyUnique="false" ignoreNameCollision="false">
                    <nameCol name="chg"/>
                    <orderType>BY_NAME</orderType>
                    <orderKind>ASC</orderKind>
                </level>
            </multiLevelHierarchy>
        </multiLevelDimension>
        <multiLevelDimension dataTableId="b24aaebb-7ce3-42a9-bab0-a54bc4c4b896" isTimeDimension="false" isDefaultTimeDimension="false" isIndexingByRange="false" id="ed48052e-2c11-48a8-9407-c4854b163cb6" name="Phase">
            <multiLevelHierarchy hasAllLevel="true" allLevelName="All-Level" allMemberName="All" name="Phase" isDefault="true">
                <level name="phase" nameUnique="false" nameUniqueInParent="false" keyUnique="false" ignoreNameCollision="false">
                    <nameCol name="phase"/>
                    <orderType>BY_NAME</orderType>
                    <orderKind>ASC</orderKind>
                </level>
            </multiLevelHierarchy>
        </multiLevelDimension>
        <timeWizardDimension isDefaultTimeDimension="false" isIndexingByRange="true" from="2018-06-01T00:00:00.000" to="2018-07-31T00:00:00.000" dataTableId="c41cc2b5-1412-4da1-8e0e-3bd1b07e9d66" unknownMemberName="" id="b545bf65-ec47-4267-a4f1-a8df35096bc4" name="Time">
            <timeHierarchy hasAllLevel="true" allLevelName="All-L" allMemberName="All-M" name="Time" isDefault="true" defaultMemberName="">
                <factAggregationType>MEMBER_AND_ANCESTORS</factAggregationType>
                <level name="Year" type="YEAR">
                    <useRelativeKey>false</useRelativeKey>
                </level>
                <level name="Month" type="MONTH" nameFormat="">
                    <useRelativeKey>false</useRelativeKey>
                </level>
                <level name="Day" type="DAY" nameFormat="">
                    <useRelativeKey>false</useRelativeKey>
                </level>
            </timeHierarchy>
            <timeWizardColumn name="start"/>
        </timeWizardDimension>
        <cube id="b9aceb66-c3dc-4d20-9f74-1ada8769cf75" name="Changes" description="">
            <defaultFacts measureGroupName="Facts" partitioningLevelName="" partitioningType="NONE" newGeneration="true" dataTableId="c41cc2b5-1412-4da1-8e0e-3bd1b07e9d66" aggregateDataSourceFacts="false" unresolvedRowsBehavior="ERROR">
                <rowFactAggregationType>ADD_ROW</rowFactAggregationType>
                <measure name="# changes" aggregationType="SUM">
                    <rollupHierarchy></rollupHierarchy>
                    <dataColumn name="#changes"/>
                    <cellProperties></cellProperties>
                    <emptyIsZero>false</emptyIsZero>
                </measure>
                <measure name="# changes close" aggregationType="CLOSE">
                    <rollupHierarchy>[Time].[Time]</rollupHierarchy>
                    <dataColumn name="#changes"/>
                    <cellProperties></cellProperties>
                    <emptyIsZero>false</emptyIsZero>
                </measure>
                <links dimensionId="0c4cf980-73d9-4c42-ae47-a300421c29a2">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="chg"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
                <links dimensionId="ed48052e-2c11-48a8-9407-c4854b163cb6">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="phase"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
                <links dimensionId="b545bf65-ec47-4267-a4f1-a8df35096bc4">
                    <viewLinks type="RANGE_FROM_TO">
                        <toColumns name="start"/>
                        <toColumns name="end"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
            </defaultFacts>
            <defaultFacts measureGroupName="Facts - delta" partitioningLevelName="" partitioningType="NONE" newGeneration="true" dataTableId="aea29582-84e2-4ef4-a169-5d9549141ba6" aggregateDataSourceFacts="false" unresolvedRowsBehavior="ERROR">
                <rowFactAggregationType>ADD_ROW</rowFactAggregationType>
                <measure name="# changes (based on delta)" aggregationType="SUM">
                    <rollupHierarchy></rollupHierarchy>
                    <dataColumn name="delta"/>
                    <cellProperties></cellProperties>
                    <emptyIsZero>false</emptyIsZero>
                </measure>
                <links dimensionId="0c4cf980-73d9-4c42-ae47-a300421c29a2">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="chg"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
                <links dimensionId="ed48052e-2c11-48a8-9407-c4854b163cb6">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="phase"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
                <links dimensionId="b545bf65-ec47-4267-a4f1-a8df35096bc4">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="date"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
            </defaultFacts>
        </cube>
        <localization enabled="false"/>
        <script>
            <content>-- 
-- Automatically migrated from an old XML file definition format (v2.0.4 or before) 
-- 

-- 
-- Drop all calc. members, sets and functions declared at schema/cube levels 
-- 

DROP *


-- 
-- Functions 
-- 

-- 
-- Sets 
-- 

-- 
-- Calculated Measures/Members 
-- 

CREATE MEMBER [#changes ITD] as Aggregate( compactSet(NULL:[Time].[Time].currentMember) , [Measures].[# changes (based on delta)] )</content>
        </script>
    </schemaDefinition>
</schemaFactory>
```

Comment: Thank you. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with regular MDX following the approach given by [purple frog](https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2013/04/mdx-between-start-date-and-end-date/). Unfortunately the standard solution provided by icCube does not support the "end-of-period-interval" problem as indicated in my question.

I have rebuild the problem in enclosed icCube scheme for reference, might someone else run into a similar problem. At the end of this solution I have added the icCube schema as XML code.

- 1st - the data
  (LEFT: data set for Ranged Dimension II - but does not work for phases, RIGHT: data set that provides the required result)
  [image: LEFT: data set for Ranged Dimension II - but does not work for phases, RIGHT: data set that provides the required result]
- INCORRECT RESULT - the MDX based on LEFT - ranged dimension:
  [image: incorrect result - the highlighted values should not be there]
- CORRECT RESULT - the MDX based on the RIGHT data set:
  [image: correct result]

A few considerations:
- Notice that in the "CORRECT RESULT" the "1" value for 2018 Jun has been removed. This might seem unexpected but it is in line with the definition of the problem: show the value of the end of the selected period (in this case: month). And as it has phase "e" has been ended 13 June, it is empty at 30 June.

Hope you benefit from this too.

Here is the XML builder schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<schemaFactory revisionNumber="7">
    <schemaDefinition name="Phases - ranged dimension II" description="issue description StackOverflow" group="StackOverflow" loadOnStartup="false">
        <activateIncrementalLoad>false</activateIncrementalLoad>
        <useUnknownMembersInFacts>false</useUnknownMembersInFacts>
        <autoCleanUpTableColumns>false</autoCleanUpTableColumns>
        <useFactPartitioning>false</useFactPartitioning>
        <callGarbageCollector>NONE</callGarbageCollector>
        <backup>NONE</backup>
        <nonEmptyCachePolicy>NONE</nonEmptyCachePolicy>
        <nonEmptyCacheType>REGULAR</nonEmptyCacheType>
        <nonEmptyCachePersistency>MEMORY</nonEmptyCachePersistency>
        <storagePolicy>DEFAULT</storagePolicy>
        <hierarchyUniqueNameStyle>IncludeDimensionName</hierarchyUniqueNameStyle>
        <inMemoryDS name="manual">
            <memoryDataTable tableName="facts" rowLimit="-1" id="c41cc2b5-1412-4da1-8e0e-3bd1b07e9d66">
                <column name="start" tableType="STRING" type="DATE" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="end" tableType="STRING" type="DATE" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="phase" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="chg" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="#changes" tableType="STRING" type="INTEGER" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <addRowNumber>false</addRowNumber>
                <stringDateConverter>d MMM, yyyy</stringDateConverter>
                <stringDateConverterLocale>en</stringDateConverterLocale>
                <trimStrings>true</trimStrings>
                <columnSeparator>;</columnSeparator>
                <commentMarker>#</commentMarker>
                <dataAsString>start;end;phase;chg;#changes
1 January, 2018;1 February, 2018; a;chg001;1
1 February, 2018;5 March, 2018;b;chg001;1
5 March, 2018;20 March, 2018;c;chg001;1
20 March, 2018;20 March, 2018;d;chg001;1
20 March, 2018;3 June, 2018;e;chg001;1
</dataAsString>
            </memoryDataTable>
            <memoryDataTable tableName="phases" rowLimit="-1" id="b24aaebb-7ce3-42a9-bab0-a54bc4c4b896">
                <column name="phase" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <addRowNumber>false</addRowNumber>
                <stringDateConverter></stringDateConverter>
                <trimStrings>true</trimStrings>
                <columnSeparator>,</columnSeparator>
                <commentMarker>#</commentMarker>
                <dataAsString>phase
a
b
c
d
e
</dataAsString>
            </memoryDataTable>
            <memoryDataTable tableName="changes" rowLimit="-1" id="8ba9aaca-0d93-49b1-851f-4f325e05bbbe">
                <column name="chg" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <addRowNumber>false</addRowNumber>
                <stringDateConverter></stringDateConverter>
                <trimStrings>true</trimStrings>
                <columnSeparator>;</columnSeparator>
                <commentMarker>#</commentMarker>
                <dataAsString>chg
chg001
chg002
chg003</dataAsString>
            </memoryDataTable>
            <memoryDataTable tableName="facts - delta" rowLimit="-1" id="aea29582-84e2-4ef4-a169-5d9549141ba6">
                <column name="date" tableType="STRING" type="DATE" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="phase" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="chg" tableType="STRING" type="STRING" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <column name="delta" tableType="STRING" type="INTEGER" selected="true" primaryKey="false" nullObjectAsString=""/>
                <addRowNumber>false</addRowNumber>
                <stringDateConverter>d MMM, yyyy</stringDateConverter>
                <stringDateConverterLocale>en</stringDateConverterLocale>
                <trimStrings>true</trimStrings>
                <columnSeparator>;</columnSeparator>
                <commentMarker>#</commentMarker>
                <dataAsString>date;phase;chg;delta
1 January, 2018;a;chg001;1
1 February, 2018;b;chg001;1
5 March, 2018;c;chg001;1
20 March, 2018;d;chg001;1
20 March, 2018;e;chg001;1
1 February, 2018;a;chg001; -1
5 March, 2018;b;chg001;-1
20 March, 2018;c;chg001;-1
20 March, 2018;d;chg001;-1
13 June, 2018;e;chg001;-1
</dataAsString>
            </memoryDataTable>
        </inMemoryDS>
        <multiLevelDimension dataTableId="8ba9aaca-0d93-49b1-851f-4f325e05bbbe" isTimeDimension="false" isDefaultTimeDimension="false" isIndexingByRange="false" id="0c4cf980-73d9-4c42-ae47-a300421c29a2" name="Change">
            <multiLevelHierarchy hasAllLevel="true" allLevelName="All-Level" allMemberName="All" name="Change" isDefault="true">
                <level name="change" nameUnique="false" nameUniqueInParent="false" keyUnique="false" ignoreNameCollision="false">
                    <nameCol name="chg"/>
                    <orderType>BY_NAME</orderType>
                    <orderKind>ASC</orderKind>
                </level>
            </multiLevelHierarchy>
        </multiLevelDimension>
        <multiLevelDimension dataTableId="b24aaebb-7ce3-42a9-bab0-a54bc4c4b896" isTimeDimension="false" isDefaultTimeDimension="false" isIndexingByRange="false" id="ed48052e-2c11-48a8-9407-c4854b163cb6" name="Phase">
            <multiLevelHierarchy hasAllLevel="true" allLevelName="All-Level" allMemberName="All" name="Phase" isDefault="true">
                <level name="phase" nameUnique="false" nameUniqueInParent="false" keyUnique="false" ignoreNameCollision="false">
                    <nameCol name="phase"/>
                    <orderType>BY_NAME</orderType>
                    <orderKind>ASC</orderKind>
                </level>
            </multiLevelHierarchy>
        </multiLevelDimension>
        <timeWizardDimension isDefaultTimeDimension="false" isIndexingByRange="true" from="2018-06-01T00:00:00.000" to="2018-07-31T00:00:00.000" dataTableId="c41cc2b5-1412-4da1-8e0e-3bd1b07e9d66" unknownMemberName="" id="b545bf65-ec47-4267-a4f1-a8df35096bc4" name="Time">
            <timeHierarchy hasAllLevel="true" allLevelName="All-L" allMemberName="All-M" name="Time" isDefault="true" defaultMemberName="">
                <factAggregationType>MEMBER_AND_ANCESTORS</factAggregationType>
                <level name="Year" type="YEAR">
                    <useRelativeKey>false</useRelativeKey>
                </level>
                <level name="Month" type="MONTH" nameFormat="">
                    <useRelativeKey>false</useRelativeKey>
                </level>
                <level name="Day" type="DAY" nameFormat="">
                    <useRelativeKey>false</useRelativeKey>
                </level>
            </timeHierarchy>
            <timeWizardColumn name="start"/>
        </timeWizardDimension>
        <cube id="b9aceb66-c3dc-4d20-9f74-1ada8769cf75" name="Changes" description="">
            <defaultFacts measureGroupName="Facts" partitioningLevelName="" partitioningType="NONE" newGeneration="true" dataTableId="c41cc2b5-1412-4da1-8e0e-3bd1b07e9d66" aggregateDataSourceFacts="false" unresolvedRowsBehavior="ERROR">
                <rowFactAggregationType>ADD_ROW</rowFactAggregationType>
                <measure name="# changes" aggregationType="SUM">
                    <rollupHierarchy></rollupHierarchy>
                    <dataColumn name="#changes"/>
                    <cellProperties></cellProperties>
                    <emptyIsZero>false</emptyIsZero>
                </measure>
                <measure name="# changes close" aggregationType="CLOSE">
                    <rollupHierarchy>[Phase].[Phase]</rollupHierarchy>
                    <dataColumn name="#changes"/>
                    <cellProperties></cellProperties>
                    <emptyIsZero>false</emptyIsZero>
                </measure>
                <links dimensionId="0c4cf980-73d9-4c42-ae47-a300421c29a2">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="chg"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
                <links dimensionId="ed48052e-2c11-48a8-9407-c4854b163cb6">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="phase"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
                <links dimensionId="b545bf65-ec47-4267-a4f1-a8df35096bc4">
                    <viewLinks type="RANGE_FROM_TO">
                        <toColumns name="start"/>
                        <toColumns name="end"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
            </defaultFacts>
            <defaultFacts measureGroupName="Facts - delta" partitioningLevelName="" partitioningType="NONE" newGeneration="true" dataTableId="aea29582-84e2-4ef4-a169-5d9549141ba6" aggregateDataSourceFacts="false" unresolvedRowsBehavior="ERROR">
                <rowFactAggregationType>ADD_ROW</rowFactAggregationType>
                <measure name="# changes (based on delta)" aggregationType="SUM">
                    <rollupHierarchy></rollupHierarchy>
                    <dataColumn name="delta"/>
                    <cellProperties></cellProperties>
                    <emptyIsZero>false</emptyIsZero>
                </measure>
                <links dimensionId="0c4cf980-73d9-4c42-ae47-a300421c29a2">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="chg"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
                <links dimensionId="ed48052e-2c11-48a8-9407-c4854b163cb6">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="phase"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
                <links dimensionId="b545bf65-ec47-4267-a4f1-a8df35096bc4">
                    <viewLinks type="LAST_LEVEL">
                        <toColumns name="date"/>
                    </viewLinks>
                </links>
            </defaultFacts>
        </cube>
        <localization enabled="false"/>
        <script>
            <content>-- 
-- Automatically migrated from an old XML file definition format (v2.0.4 or before) 
-- 

-- 
-- Drop all calc. members, sets and functions declared at schema/cube levels 
-- 

DROP *


-- 
-- Functions 
-- 

-- 
-- Sets 
-- 

-- 
-- Calculated Measures/Members 
-- 

</content>
        </script>
    </schemaDefinition>
</schemaFactory>
```